# MlKit Translation.getClient() returns null after MlKit dynamic initialization

Tags: android, google-mlkit

We are integrating MLKit for Language translations into a Java-based Android application. After initializing the MLKit dynamically (we disabled the Provider in AndroidManifest) and configuring the Translation Options, the Translation.getClient(options) throws a NullPointerException which prevents the use of all Translation functionality available in MlKit.

We have disabled the MlKit provider in the AndroidManifest.xml and are relying on dynamic initialization for reasons specific to our application.

```
<provider android:name="com.google.mlkit.common.internal.MlKitInitProvider"
          android:authorities="${applicationId}.mlkitinitprovider"
          tools:node="remove" />
```

We then initialize the MlKit in an Activity using its context and establish the Translator options.

```
MlKit.initialize(context);

// Create an English-German translator:
TranslatorOptions options =
        new TranslatorOptions.Builder()
                .setSourceLanguage(TranslateLanguage.ENGLISH)
                .setTargetLanguage(TranslateLanguage.GERMAN)
                .build();
final Translator englishGermanTranslator =
        Translation.getClient(options);
```

The Translator.getClient() returns null when trying to retrieve the Translator Factory from the MlKitContext which prevents the use of all Translation capabilities.

```
((TranslatorImpl.Factory)MlKitContext.getInstance().get(TranslatorImpl.Factory.class))
```

Are there any other MlKit.initialize() considerations to account for to ensure that the TranslatorImpl.Factory is available in the MlKitContext?